# Javascript - Build an async interface around an async WebSocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, es6-promise

I'm wondering if it is possible to build an async interface around a webSocket object, that is async by nature.

The webSockect object is inside a class/function that publishes a number of methods: I'd like to call this methods, send a command via websocket, wait the reply and recall the standard methods as `.then` or `.catch` - thinking like a javascript `Promise`.

```
function x() {
    myWS.sendCmdA().then( function() { doSomething; });
}

function myWS(){
  var ws = null;
  this.open = function() {
    ws = new WebSocket(....);
    ws.open = function() { ... };
    ws.onmessage = function () { ... };
  }
  this.sendCmdA = function () {
    ws.send("ABCD");
  }
}
```

Or it is better to pass a callback function(s) on the call like

```
myWS.sendCmdA( fnOk, fnErr);
```

?

Comment: Yes, you can create a `new Promise` that will "*wait the reply*" - but how to wait for the one reply to the sent command depends on the specific protocol that you are using.

Comment: Ok, I can create a Promise inside the sendCmdA() function but I wil have the reply on the ws.onmessage function. How can I retrieve the resolve/reject handlers of the promise?

Comment: Store them in a data structure that allows matching commands to replies. When you receive a certain reply in your `onmessage` handler, look for the `resolve` function in that data structure and call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final solution I adopted:

- added two arrays to store the two possible replies

  ```
  var _resolved=[];
  var _rejected=[];
  ```
- for each request I defined a Promise as following:

  ```
    this.ambd002GetLocks = function(locks){
      return new Promise(
        function( resolve, rejected){
            _resolved['ambd002'] = resolve;
            _rejected['ambd002'] = rejected;
            ws.send("{\"parn1\":"+locks+", \"cmd\":\"ambd002GetLocks\"}");
        }
     );
   }
  ```
- when I receive the reply on onmessage handler I check the result and recall one of the stored function, using a specified index:

  ```
  ws.onmessage = function got_packet(msg) {
            console.info("RxWs: " + msg.data);

            ...
                case "ambd002GetLocks":
                    if (obj.v=="ok"){
                        _resolved['ambd002'](obj);
                    } else {
                        _rejected['ambd002'](obj);
                    }
                    break;
           ...
  ```